# Add callback to $(xml).find("..").each

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to add an callback to this loop? As a way to let the app know "now it's time to do this.."..?

```
$(xml).find("book").each(function(){
    var id = $(this).find("id").text(); 
    var x = $(this).find("x").text();   
    var y = $(this).find("y").text();   
    var z = $(this).find("z").text();   

    hasItem(id, x, y, z, function(flag, id, x, y, z) {
        if(!flag) {
            //doing something
        }
    });
}); 

//add callback to tell me that all rows of xml has been read and hasItem is done reading?
```

Comment: Simply call the function. Why not?

Comment: No, there isn't. It's a synchronous operation therefore no callback is needed for the $.each. However, if `//doing something` does an asynchronous action such as ajax, you'll need to use deferred objects to track when they are all complete.

Comment: Yeah... callbacks are intended primarily for asynchronous functionality... areas where you want to release the program from blocking while processing continues in the background. However, in this case, I don't see anything that could be asynchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

even if it's an asynchronous operation, why don't you call a function once your done?

```
function done(){
    // completed...
}
var total = $(xml).find("book").length;
$(xml).find("book").each(function(index, element){
    var id = $(this).find("id").text(); 
    var x = $(this).find("x").text();   
    var y = $(this).find("y").text();   
    var z = $(this).find("z").text();  
    hasItem(id, x, y, z, function(flag, id, x, y, z) {
        if(!flag) {
            //doing something
            if(total == index+1)
               done();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I think this would be the best way. But I would suggest to declare the done function before executing the each loop.